# Ouputting array_count_values extracting key and values

Tags: php, arrays

This is probably so newbie. Basically im l

```
$count_versions = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $email_build = $row1['build_info'];
$count_versions[] = $email_build;
    }
```

Now when I use `print_r` I get this

```
Array ( [2660] => 8 [2662] => 6 [2655] => 6 [2666] => 1 )
```

Which is perfect, now all I want to do is to output those values like

```
2660 - 8 votes
2662 - 6 votes
2655 - 6 votes
2666 - 1 votes
```

When I try this it seems to break up the values back into a full array which undoes my `array_count_values` but I am stumped

I realize this `foreach` loop makes no sense but its as close as I can get, any ideas how I can basically print it out like `print_r` does it so i can put it in a table later

```
$i=0;
foreach ($count_versions as $version => $nums)
{
$i++;
echo "Version: " . $nums . " - " . $count_versions . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Inside the `foreach` you have new values now: *$version* and *$nums*. Use them to get the data you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks so easy to do it with a foreach:

```
$count_versions = array ( "2660" => 8, "2662" => 6, "2655" => 6, "2666" => 1 );

foreach ($count_versions  as $key => $value)  
    echo $key.' - '.$value.' votes<br>';
```

Comment: I guess i didnt ask the question clearly so sorry for that and i guess that made it hard for others to answer it, nonetheless the information in this one gave me an AHA moment, the problem was i was using foreach ($count_versions as $version => $nums) instead of foreach (array_count_values($count_versions) as $version => $nums)

That caused me to see each loop individually instead of grouped which threw me off, thanks guys for guiding me. The reason i choose this answer although both were technically correct was it showed me my array was the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "Version: " . $version . " - " . $nums . " votes<br />";
```